# Trying to Append multiple values to the same key in a Swift dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I tried to append different values for same key in dict but getting error please help to solve this..
 both below dictionary initializations giving errors.

```
     //one way of declaring dict 
     public var List = Dictionary<String, Array<Any>>()
     // second way of declaring dict
     public var List = [String: [String]]()

            let bDDR = "b4474rb74g"


            let pressure = 20
            List[bDDR].append(pressure)
            //error is: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : [String]]' with an index of type '[String]'

            let voltageValue = 3.90

            let tempValue = 97
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: It is always a good idea to copy/paste your real code  (`bDDR` != `BDDR`)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot append it in place. Because `List[BDDR]` gives you a constant copy of the array. You have to assign the list array to a variable, append the value and then set ti back to the dict.

```
var list = List[BDDR]
list?.append(pressure)
List[bDDR] = list
```

Also, `public var List = [String: [String]]()`, will not work, because you are appending an `Int` instead of a String. `public var List = Dictionary<String, Array<Any>>()` will work because Int is also Any.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you wan to overwrite old values

```
List.updateValue([pressure],forKey:bDDR)
```

if you want to append

```
List.updateValue(List[bDDR]! + [pressure],forKey:bDDR)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List.updateValue([pressure.description], forKey: bDDR)
```